# How to exclude resource/library from OpenApi 3 documentation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I need to exclude endpoints from the documentation which are added to the project through the maven dependency.

My OpenApi configuration:

```
    @Configuration public class OpenApiConfiguration {
    
        @Value("${app.version:unknown}")
        private String version;
    
        @Bean
        public OpenAPI openAPI() {
            return new OpenAPI()
                    .info(new Info()
                            .description("Generated OpenAPI 3.0 API")
                            .version(version));
        } 
}
```

My springdoc dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.8</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have tried to use this in my application.yml, bit it didn't work, endpoints and modeles from maven dependencies were always shown in Open Api docs.

```
springdoc:
  packages-to-exclude:
```

The only thing that works is adding paths-to-match or paths-to-exclude in the application.yml. But I want exclude the entire lib and avoid listing all the paths.

```
springdoc:
    paths-to-exclude:
    paths-to-match:
```

I use java 8.
Is there a way to exclude the library from the Open Api documentation?

Comment: How did you use packages to exclude exactly ?

Comment: You will need to use the fully qualified package name to exclude the resources properly.

Comment: I used `springdoc: packages-to-exclude: my.package` in my application.yml. It didn't work in java 8. The beanType of classes from maven dependency is com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176 and package is null in java 8. There is a code snippet in org.springdoc.api that calculate a package for classes: org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource#isFilterCondition. And there is a code snipper that add packages with null value in swagger documentation: org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource#isPackageToScan `protected boolean isPackageToScan(Package aPackage) { if (aPackage == null) return true;`

Comment: Is there a different way to exclude a package from OpenApi documentation?

Comment: olga You have workaround with paths. Could you provide a minimal sample, that shows packages-to-exclude not working in your case ?